# Where to get a 3D human face model as .obj file

Tags: 3d, ios, blender, iphone

Related to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344430/opengles-display-human-face-in-iphone), I got an idea to go for an unique 3D human face model which fits all the the human faces.

1) Where can I get a ready made human head model? I have seen some tools like Blender where I could create it, but it seems to require a big effort. Sites like [turbosquid](http://www.turbosquid.com) don't seem to have these unique face models.

2) Is there anywhere I can use [candide](http://www.icg.isy.liu.se/candide/) in ios to render a 3D face?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Poser](http://poser.smithmicro.com/freefigures.html) they have many 3D character models. You might even find some custom creations floating around online if you do a search.

Another option if you want a 'unique' face is to use photogammetry, which is basically using multiple photos to construct a 3D model. I know there is at least one app on iPhone that does this, unfortunately I can not remember the name...

Autodesk also has one called [123D Catch](http://www.123dapp.com/catch)